# Wrapping blog posts within a <div> that alternates between col-4 and col-8

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm setting up a blog page layout where I need to display col-4 and col-8 columns alternately, rather than manually going inside each  and fetching the required posts.

I have tried adding the loop inside the col-4, but I'm not being able to figure out how to alternate between col-4 and col-8

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;

    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'nopaging' => true,
    );

    $this_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>
     <section class="ftco-section ftco-project" id="projects-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row justify-content-center pb-5">
          <div class="col-md-12 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
              <h1 class="big big-2">Projects</h1>
            <h2 class="mb-4">Our Projects</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
            <?php if ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : $this_query->the_post(); ?> 
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="project img ftco-animate d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>');">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="text text-center p-4">
                            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <span>Web Design</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="project img ftco-animate d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>');?>/images/project-5.jpg);">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="text text-center p-4">
                            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <span>Web Design</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <?php endwhile; 
                  wp_reset_postdata();
                  else : ?>
                  <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts found.' ); ?></p>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
```

I want the col-4 and col-8 to populate automatically and alternately. I have tried doing so, but the blog posts do not alternate between col-4 and col-8, rather it just populates all the blog posts in col-4 div.

Comment: If you want to output the exact same code in both cases, _except_ for the class name - then you should not try to do this in two separate loops to begin with. Just use a variable to hold the class name (or even just the number, 4 or 8), and switch that between the two values …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php $class = "col-md-4"; // 2nd element class ?> 
<?php while ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : $this_query->the_post(); ?> 
<?php
     if($class == "col-md-4") { $class = "col-md-8"; }
    else if ($class == "col-md-8") { $class = "col-md-4"; }

?>
                <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                    <div class="project img ftco-animate d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>');">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="text text-center p-4">
                            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <span>Web Design</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <?php endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x=0;

if ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $this_query->have_posts() ) : $this_query->the_post();
        $class_array = array('col-4', 'col-8');
        $col_class = $class_array[$x%2];
        $x++;

    <div class="<?php echo $col_class ?>"></div>

    endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```